# import html file in react-typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to import a HTML file (.html) into react js - typescript (.tsx) as a component

but it gives me this ERROR:

> error - ./pages/SM_login/Facebook.html
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

| 
|

Here is my code:

```
const facebook = require('./SM_login/facebook.html'); 

   export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <li>                          
                    <iframe src={facebook }></iframe>
                 </li>
           </div>            
    );
}
```

}

Comment: The correct way to do this is to convert your html file into jsx syntax and insert directly inside <li> tag

Comment: @movila that's too hard, because the HTML file is too large

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. add code to string variable

Inside your `./SM_login/facebook.html` file, wrap all the code inside a backticks (``) and name this string with a variable name such as `iframeCode`

```
export default iframeCode = `<html>...</html>`
```

#### 2. rename file to typescript

rename your `facebook.html` into `facebook.ts`

#### 3. import html code as stringified code

inside your code do following with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
import facebook from './SM_login/facebook.ts'

export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <li>                          
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: facebook}} />
                 </li>
           </div>            
    );
}
```

Comment: you save my life :)

Comment: I tried implementing this but got "Cannot find name 'iframeCode'.

Answer (score -1):

According to react documentation you can't import a module using **require** keyword you have to use es6 keyword **import** your code should be like this

```
import facebook from "./facebook.html";

const CustomDocument = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>
          <iframe src={facebook}></iframe>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
}

export default CustomDocument;
```

Comment: dosen't work  !, it gives me this error: Cannot find module './SM_login/facebook.html' or its corresponding type declarations